# Having multi lines in bash command substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a very long bash command inside a command substitution like following:

```
$( comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand )
```

I want to know if there is a way to break this command into shorter lines for the sake of readability like following:

```
$( com 
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   nd )
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can mask the newline with `\`.

```
$( com\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa\
nd )
```

The `\` tells the shell to ignore the newline.

Comment: The ``\`` part is correct, but you can not indent the subsequent lines. (At least not in the middle of words as in the example.)

Comment: yeah copy and paste is a curse! :)

Comment: I checked it and it works even having indentations!

Comment: @Coffe_Mug It works only if `commaaaaaaaaaaaaaand` is actually `command with a lot of options and | maybe pipes etc`. Otherwise it doesn't work with indentation.Try `echo $(ec\<NEWLINEHERE>ho a)`, works while `echo $(ec\<NEWLINE HERE><INDENTATION HERE>ho a)` produce *ec: command not found*. While `echo $(echo Hello,\<NEWLINE HERE> World)`[note the space after newline] and `echo $(echo Hello,<NEWLINE HERE><INDENTATION HERE> World)` do exactly the same things.

Comment: @Bakuriu : to be fair, your last example it does exactly the same thing because you forgot to surround the echo parameters with " (as in : `echo "$(echo "Hello,\<NEWLINE HERE> World")"` ) so the outer echo receives several parameters and separate them with only 1 default separator.

Comment: @OlivierDulac **That's exactly the point I wanted to make!** Using a single space or multiple spaces to separate options/different commands doesn't make a difference, hence the indentation after the newline doesn't have any effect. If you put the line break inside *one* command(or option) than indentation *does* matter.

Comment: @Bakuriu: ok ^^ But I wanted to precise, as it could also be read as "`\<NEWLINE><indentation>something` is equivalent to `\<NEWLINE><anotherindentation>something`", which is false in general and only true when the newline and indentation are just (unnacounted for) separators.

Answer (score 11):

If there are pipe `|` symbols in a long Bash command line, there may be no need for the backslash `\` to mask the newline because the pipe `|` symbols can be used for formatting your code as well.

```
# example
ls | 
 cat -n | 
 tail   | 
 head
```

Comment: +1. Same with `&&` and `||`

Comment: oh my, +1, before seing this I always did "commands \<CR> | commands" (which has the advantage of being quite readable, though, as the pipe begin the line, clearly visible. But having to remember to add the "\<CR>" makes it cumbersome)

Comment: Related: [Where are bash line continuations after && and || documented?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253518/135943)