# Where are bash line continuations after && and || documented?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have seen this construct in scripts a lot and used it myself, but it bothers me that I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Example:

```
[ -f file1 ] &&
[ -f file2 ] &&
echo "Both files exist." ||
echo "One or the other file doesn't exist."
```

This could also be done with backslashes before the newlines, as mentioned in `man bash`:

```
If a \<newline> pair appears,  and  the  backslash  is  not
itself  quoted,  the \<newline> is treated as a line continuation (that
is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).
```

Example:

```
[ -f file1 ] && \
[ -f file2 ] && \
echo "Both files exist." || \
echo "One or the other file doesn't exist."
```

...but this doesn't seem to be necessary.  The first version above works even without the backslashes.

Where can I find this in `man bash`?  (Also, is this `bash` specific or POSIX compliant?)

Comment: If you’re looking for official bash or POSIX documentation, see Gilles’s answer.   But this is discussed in [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216) — [More observations on `;`, `&`, `(` and `)`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#159664).

Comment: @G-Man, I guess that wasn't directed at me?  Just for future readers?  As I said in the question, *"it bothers me that I can't seem to find it in the documentation."*  I already knew how it works, so this was indeed just a request for the official documentation.  :)

Comment: Even in the case of arrays, there is an implicit line continuation: `names=( Rama Soma<newline>
Sita Diya )`. Python clearly describes these [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) but the Bash documentation doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A newline is ignored in a few contexts where there is manifestly an unterminated command. These contexts include after a control operator (`&&`, `||`, `|`, `&`, `;`, `;;`, but not `!`).

I don't see this documented in the bash manual.

In POSIX, it's specified via the [grammar rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02). Wherever the rules have `linebreak`, you can have zero or more line breaks.

Comment: +1, I didn't knew it worked for the simple pipe ( | ) .  I wish we could also put them on the next line, for readability, but it doesn't work that way (if doing that, you need to espace the preceding newline).

Comment: @OlivierDulac How could that possibly work? When it's processing the current command line, how is it supposed to know that you're planning to type `|` at the beginning of the next line? Remember, the shell is also used interactively, not just in scripts, and the grammar is the same.

Comment: @Barmar : I know, I do know this (wrote compilers at school ^^)... I said "I wish", and it is not a very plausible wish

Comment: I wish bash supported an ellipsis (...) for line continuation. It would prevent a lot of logic bugs. But we can't have everything.

Comment: @DocSalvager, can you give an example of a logic bug that would help prevent?  I have a hard time seeing it....

Comment: As you found, ending lines with && and || is not well documented and thus uncommon (except in your shop apparently). On seeing the example, my first thought was "syntax error". I've been writing shell script for decades and still had to look it up and run it to prove it is correct. Lines ending in '&' (run in background) are more common to me (and erroneous key repeats as well). Though this example works, using multiple && and || clauses is highly unreliable due to how they differ from the expected if-then logic. The epllipsis in english means "more to follow" so that makes more sense to me.

Comment: @DocSalvager, I wouldn't actually use the code as I wrote it—it was an illustration.  Without the last line (the else clause) I would use it that way, though.  (For "if this and this then do that" `this && this2 && that` is fine but for an `else` clause I'd use an actual `if then else fi`.)

Comment: @Gilles: What do you mean by “A newline is ignored … after a control operator (…, `&`, `;`, …).”? If I type `foo &&`, `foo ||`, or `foo |`, the shell prints a `> ` prompt (PS2) and keeps on reading. (And, if I say one of those in a script, the shell reads the next line and appends it to the current one.  In both cases, it is the same behavior as if I typed a ``\`` at the end of the line.) But if I type `foo &` or `foo ;`, the command is executed immediately.

Comment: @G-Man This thread was about scripts. An interactive shell executes a command as soon as it's read a syntactically valid command, so e.g. `foo` or `foo &` is executed immediately (because both are valid commands on their own) but `foo &&` isn't (because there has to be a command after `&&`).

Comment: Might be worth noting that  linebreak is treated as `;` when part of compound command in `{...}`

Comment: @Sergiy Not just in `{…}`, anywhere in a compound command except I'm a few places where a `;` would be invalid. And since the whole script is a compound command, that's anywhere except I'm those few places (and in quotes of course). That was the point of the question: why does it not happen sometimes?

Comment: Regarding @G-Man's comment, I too don't understand in what sense a newline is *ignored* after `&` (or `;`).  Thinking on it, I guess that's true in the strictly mathematical sense that a compiler author would see it, but taking into account common usage in shell scripts, it's clearer to say that a newline isn't *required* in those places.  Right?  (Which is just as true after `&&` and `|` and `||`, except it sounds funny to say a newline is "not required" when most people don't even realize a newline is an option at all in those places.)

Comment: @Wildcard Both statements are true, but the point of this thread was that newlines can be present after a control operator. Why would you distinguish between operators? That would only make things confusing since there is no difference.