# Run multiple piped grep commands from a list in bash

Tags: bash, ssh, grep, sql

As part of my security job, I analyze dozens of Google Chrome history files each day using sqlite3 over SSH.

There are a few dozen authorized "safe" sites each user is allowed to navigate to.  For my purposes, I don't care about these safe sites.  To list the URLs of each history file and ignore the safe websites, I use `grep -v` and list each safe site as follows:

```
sqlite3 /home/me/HistoryDatabaseFile.db "select * from urls order by url;" | grep -v safesite1.com | grep -v safesite2.com | grep -v safesite3.com | grep -v safesite4.com
```

and on and on.  My command has grown to at least 20 lines and is becoming unmanageable. Is there any way I could show the user's list of URLs while excluding my safe sites in a listed format?  I'm imagining something like:

```
safesite1.com
safesite2.com
safesite3.com
```

and then bringing that list into the command.  It can be internal or external- I don't really care as long as it ends up outputting in bash.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something like

```
grep -vf safe_websites inputfile
```

`-v` to invert the matches you already know, and `-f` is to obtain patterns from the file `safe_websites`.

Comment: Awesome!  Can you clarify the syntax in this example though?  Trying "grep -vf /home/me/safesites.txt" only worked to exclude the first site in my list, and "grep -vf /home/me/safesites.txt inputfile" gave me the error: "grep: inputfile: No such file or directory"

Comment: @JaredDalton `inputfile` is the input file, that you would like to `grep`. In your question you get the input from the `sqlite3` command, so you don't need it. `grep -vf /home/me/safesites.txt` should work, though. What's the content of `/home/me/safesites.txt`?

Comment: In my current test, on the first line of safesites.txt I have       www.silversneakers.com    and then I pressed Enter for a new line, and on the second line I have     www.medicare.gov

Comment: Don't forget that unless you force a fixed string match (`-F` or `--fixed-strings`), `.` will match any single character - potentially letting through nefarious sites of the form `safesite2Xcom.com` - and unless you enforce a whole-word or whole-line match, things like `unsafesite2.com`

Answer (score 0):

Another option you may consider is using the `egrep` form of grep, which will allow you to use Extended regular expressions so you can put multiple targets in a single string thusly:

`egrep -v "safesite1\.com|safesite2\.com|safesite3\.com"`

Details of these and other extended REs can be had from `man 7 re_format`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should use the `-f` option to `grep`, and provide a list of patterns for `grep` to use.

However, you also mention having special characters in your URLs, which makes sense.  The correct answer is to use the `-F` flag to `grep` to only consider the patterns as fixed strings.

So to accomplish what you want:

First, put your list of safe websites in a file, for example `/tmp/safelist.txt`.  This should look something like:

```
safesite1.com
safesite2.com
safesite3.com
```

Next, call `grep` on that file like so:

```
sqlite3 /home/me/HistoryDatabaseFile.db "select * from urls order by url;" | grep -vFf /tmp/safelist.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

It turns out my problem had to do with the data I was trying to parse.  If I tried using the test output

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

and then using `grep -vf file.txt` to remove a, b, and c it worked like a charm.  Since I was instead trying to ignore a bunch of websites with a variety of special characters, it never worked for me, even when trying to manipulate an outputted .txt file of my sql query.

My solution to make my command more readable, ultimately, was to use the backslash (`\`) to split up my command onto multiple lines and make it easier to read:

```
sqlite3 /home/me/HistoryDatabaseFile.db "select * from urls order by url;" | \
grep -v safesite1.com | \
grep -v safesite2.com | \
grep -v safesite3.com | \
grep -v safesite4.com | \
grep -v safesite5.com
```

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: That means you're spawning a separate `grep` process for every website you want to exclude.  Somewhat horrifying.

Comment: Also, [you don't need to escape a newline after a pipe](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253518/135943).