# How to catch and handle nonzero exit status within a Bash function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, exit, error-handling

Say I have the following (pointless) Bash function:

```
myfunc() {
    ls
    failfailfail
    uptime
}
```

I run it as follows:

```
myfunc || echo "Something is wrong."
```

What I want to happen is `ls` runs (as it should), `failfailfail` does not work (since it doesn't exist), and `uptime` doesn't run. The return value of the function would be nonzero, and the error message would be shown. The return value doesn't have to be the exact exit status of the failed command, it just shouldn't be zero.

What actually happens is I get the output of `ls`, followed by "-bash: failfailfail: command not found", followed by the output of `uptime`. The error message is not shown, because the failed exit status is getting eaten.

`set -e` has no useful effect, either within the function or in the scope where the function is called. The only way I can get this to work the way I want is:

```
myfunc() {
    ls || return $?
    failfailfail || return $?
    uptime || return $?
}
```

But this seems awfully repetitive and ugly. Is there another way to clean this up?

Answer (score 3):

Under `set -e`, the non-existence of `failfailfail` causes the whole script to exit (or the subshell, if the function is executed in a subshell).

If you don't need to modify the shell state from the function, you can run it in a subshell.

```
myfunc() (
    set -e
    ls
    failfailfail
    uptime
)
```

Another approach in bash is to set an `ERR` [trap](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) to execute `return`. If you want to make it a local setting, you need to restore the old trap value, which is a little cumbersome.

```
myfunc() {
    local old_ERR_trap=$(trap -p ERR)
    if [[ -z $old_ERR_trap ]]; then old_ERR_trap="trap - ERR"; fi
    trap 'local ret=$?; eval "$old_ERR_trap"; return $ret' ERR
    ls
    failfailfail
    uptime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can make it simpler is by combining it all in one command but it makes the script a bit harder to maintain than your last version:

```
myfunc() {
    ls && failfailfail && uptime || return $?
}
```

Comment: You can put [line breaks after `&&`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253518/135943), which would make this easier to maintain IMO.  You don't need backslashes for that, either.

Answer (score 0):

Given that they are all simple commands, you could do it something like the following:

```
myfunc() {
  ls &&
  failfailfail &&
  uptime ||
  return $?
}
```

Comment: It's interesting but I think it may cause more confusion that way.

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer, you should edit the existing one. Your answer doesn't need to be a separate answer from the previous one.

Comment: @MAChitgarha this is from three years ago.

Comment: @Wildcard I know, but some people may search for a solution, now. Editing the previous answer is more helpful than adding an answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things are better put in a Makefile, which handles this sort of thing.

```
#!/bin/bash
myfunc() { # watch out for tabs!
        make -f - <<!
default:
        ls -d
        failfailfail
        uptime
!
}
```

Comment: This feels... devious.